# Why does 2**-1025 != 0.0 in Python

Tags: python, floating-point, precision, ieee-754

From the specs of IEEE754, a float coded on 64 bits has 11bits for the exponent and 52 bits for the mantissa. Hence, the smaller number that could be coded as a float should be `2**(-2**10)`. The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) which I believe is true, give a more exact value of `2**-1022` whose decimal value is approximately `2.2250738585072014e-308`.

But, with Python, I can use as float numbers such as `2**-1052`, etc. The actual limit on my computer is `2**-1074`. From this [page of the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html), Python usually conforms to IEEE754.

At the same time, the maximal value is `2**1023`, which is the given value by the IEEE754 standard.

- Why is it so?
- Does anyone has an explanation?
- What is the actual encoding of a float in Python?
- Why does the range for the exponent, which is equal to `1074+1023+1`, ie `2098`, is not a power of `2`?

Comment: Probably because Python `float` doesn't conform to the IEEE754 standard.

Comment: Yes, but where can I have more infos?

Comment: BTW, on my env `-1075` also works.

Comment: What about `2**-1076` and the following?

Comment: My guess is on denormal numbers. While -1022 is the smallest exponent you can have, you can still represent smaller numbers then that by making the mantissa smaller.

Comment: "Hence, the smaller number that could be coded as a float should be 2**(-2**10)" --> No.  Smallest is more like `2**(1 - 2**10 - (52-1))`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: That looks like an answer to me.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense and I can verify on my computer that the mantissa is very short for these small number. Anyone having a link or willing to explain more precisely is welcomed! 

Comment: @goodvibration 2**-1075 is exactly half the minimal denormalized 64bits floating point 2**-1074. It should be rounded to nearest even, that is 0.0 if VM is strictly conforming to IEEE 754... What do you get? In which configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the Python documentation does not specify that IEEE-754 is used. The choice of floating-point implementation is up to each Python implementation. IEEE-754 is very popular but not universal.

In the IEEE-754 basic 64-bit binary floating-point format (*binary64*), there is a one-bit sign field *s*, an eleven-bit exponent field *e*, and a 52-bit primary significand field *f* (for “fraction”).

The sign bit is 0 for positive and 1 for negative.

If *e* is all one bits (1111111111, or 2047 in decimal), the object represents an infinity (if *f* is zero) or a NaN (if *f* is not zero). (“NaN” stands for “Not a Number”).

If *e* is neither all zero bits nor all one bits, then it represents an exponent *E* = *e* − 1023, and the *f* field is used to form a number *F* that is 1.*f* (that is, the binary numeral “1.” followed by the 52 bits of *f*). (Equivalently, if we regard *f* as a binary numeral, we can say *F* = 1 + *f* • 2<sup>−52</sup>.) The number represented is (−1)<sup>*s*</sup> • 2<sup>*E*</sup> • *F*. These are called normal numbers.

If *e* is all zero bits, then it represents an exponent *E* = 1 − 1023, and the *f* field is used to form a number *F* that is 0.*f* (that is, the binary numeral “0.” followed by the 52 bits of *f*). (Equivalently, we can say *F* = 0 + *f* • 2<sup>−52</sup>.) Again, the number represented is (−1)<sup>*s*</sup> • 2<sup>*E*</sup> • *F*. These are called subnormal numbers.

Note that *e* = 1 and *e* = 0 represent the same exponent *E*, 1 − 1023 = −1022, but change the first bit of *F* from 1 to 0. *F* is the significand (the fraction part) of the floating-point number. (People sometimes refer to *f* as the significand<sup>1</sup>, but that is incorrect. It is only the field that provides most of the encoding of the mathematical significand. As we see above, the exponent field also contributes to forming the actual significand, *F*.)

The smallest positive number occurs when *s* is zero, *e* is zero, and *f* is 1 (0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001). Then *E* = −1022 and *F* = 0 + 1 • 2<sup>−52</sup>, so the number represented is (−1)<sup>0</sup> • 2<sup>−1022</sup> • 2<sup>−52</sup> = 2<sup>−1074</sup>.

The largest finite number occurs when *s* is zero, *e* is 2046 (11111111110), and *f* is all ones (1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111). *E* = 2046 − 1023 = 1023. Note that *f*, interpreted as an integer, is 2<sup>52</sup>−1, so *F* = 1 + *(2<sup>52</sup>−1) • 2<sup>−52</sup> = 1 + 1 − 2<sup>−52</sup> = 2 - 2<sup>−52</sup>. So the value represented is (−1)<sup>0</sup> • 2<sup>1023</sup> • (2 - 2<sup>−52</sup>) = 2<sup>1024</sup> − 2<sup>971</sup>.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> The significand is sometimes referred to as the “mantissa,” but that is an old term for the fraction portion of a logarithm. It is not entirely appropriate for floating-point numbers, as mantissas are logarithmic while significands are linear.

Comment: Wow, that's an impressive answer. Where did you get this knowledge from?

Comment: @Colas: Reading the IEEE-754 standard and working with floating-point arithmetic. A lot of it is not truly complicated, just a bunch of parts that you need to be familiar with individually.

Comment: Ok, so you mean this is not just true for Python but is part of the IEE-754 standard?

Comment: @Colas: Python does not strictly specify what floating-point format is used. Many Python implementations use the IEEE-754 standard to some degree. The IEEE-754 standard is strict about the values represented and the various behaviors it defines.

Answer (score 2):

[binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) encodes most values with a biased exponent and a 53 bit significand.

With biased exponent as 1 or more<sup>**</sup>, the value is: 1.the_52_bit_encoded_"mantissa" * 2<sup>exponent - bias</sup>.

With biased exponent as 0, the value is: 0.the_52_bit_encoded_"mantissa" * 2<sup>1 - bias</sup>.

OP is in the right idea for *normal* values.  But there exist *sub-normal* values that have various amounts of leading zeros in 0.the_52_bit_encoded_"mantissa".  The smallest non-zero is then 0.(51_zeros)1 * 2<sup>1 - bias</sup> or 2<sup>-1074</sup>.

---

<sup>**</sup> When the  biased exponent has a maximal value, the number is special: either an *infinity* or *not-a-number*.